# How to merge list of sets into one with same order?

Tags: python, list, merge, set, reduce

I have a list of list like below:-

```
set_res = [{'88194e6889', '88194e688b', '88194e68d5'},
 {'88194e6f45', '88194e6f4d'},
 {'88194e6ab3', '88194e6abb'},
 {'88194e6a8b',
  '88194e6ac3',
  '88194e6acb',
  '88194e6ad5',
  '88194e6add'},
 {'88194e61a1',
  '88194e61a3',
  '88194e61a7',
  '88194e61ab',
  '88194e61bd',
  '88194e6f49'}]
```

When I am trying to merge them into one it's not merging in correct order I have tried set.union(),reduce(),iterloops to merge evrything returns in different order.
method 1:-

```
from functools import reduce
reduce(set.union,set_res[0:5])
```

result:

```
{'88194e61a1',
 '88194e61a3',
 '88194e61a7',
 '88194e61ab',
 '88194e61bd',
 '88194e6889',
 '88194e688b',
 '88194e68d5',
 '88194e6a8b',
 '88194e6ab3',
 '88194e6abb',
 '88194e6ac3',
 '88194e6acb',
 '88194e6ad5',
 '88194e6add',
 '88194e6f45',
 '88194e6f49',
 '88194e6f4d'}
```

Method 2:-

```
set.union(*set_res[0:5])
```

result:

```
{'88194e61a1',
 '88194e61a3',
 '88194e61a7',
 '88194e61ab',
 '88194e61bd',
 '88194e6889',
 '88194e688b',
 '88194e68d5',
 '88194e6a8b',
 '88194e6ab3',
 '88194e6abb',
 '88194e6ac3',
 '88194e6acb',
 '88194e6ad5',
 '88194e6add',
 '88194e6f45',
 '88194e6f49',
 '88194e6f4d'}
```

The order of the Excepted output:-

```
['88194e6889', '88194e688b', '88194e68d5',
 '88194e6f45', '88194e6f4d',
 '88194e6ab3', '88194e6abb',
 '88194e6a8b',
  '88194e6ac3',
  '88194e6acb',
  '88194e6ad5',
  '88194e6add',
 '88194e61a1',
  '88194e61a3',
  '88194e61a7',
  '88194e61ab',
  '88194e61bd',
  '88194e6f49']
```

Any best way to perform in order to combine list of sets into one in a ordered form?

Comment: sets are unordered, so what you want seems impossible

Comment: You need a list of lists, not a list of sets.

Comment: If this were a list of lists instead of a list of sets, you can simply do `sum(set_res, [])`.

Comment: @mozway so I can convert set into list and then combine them into one?

Comment: You can turn each set into a list, but it's possible that those lists won't have the order you want either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets are unordered so you can't control the order of the elements.

The best you can achieve given your input it to keep a partial order based on the list:

```
from itertools import chain

out = list(dict.fromkeys(chain.from_iterable(set_res)))
```

output:

```
['88194e68d5', '88194e6889', '88194e688b', '88194e6f45', '88194e6f4d', '88194e6ab3', '88194e6abb', '88194e6ac3', '88194e6add', '88194e6ad5', '88194e6acb', '88194e6a8b', '88194e61a7', '88194e61bd', '88194e61ab', '88194e61a1', '88194e6f49', '88194e61a3']
```

Better example:

```
set_res = [{'B', 'A', 'C'},
           {'A', 'D'},
           {'B', 'F', 'E', 'A', 'C'}]
```

output (broken to show the origin of the elements):

```
['C', 'A', 'B',  # we can't control the order here
 'D',            # A was removed
 'E', 'F'        # A/B/C were removed, we can't control the order of E/F
]
```